# How to count the occurrence of values in one pandas Dataframe if the values to count are in another (in a faster way)?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

I have a (really big) pandas Dataframe **df**:

```
country  age  gender
Brazil    10     F
USA       20     F 
Brazil    10     F
USA       20     M
Brazil    10     M
USA       20     M
```

I have another pandas Dataframe **freq**:

```
 age  gender  counting
  10       F         0
  10       M         0
  20       F         0
```

I wanna count the pair of values in **freq** when they occur in **df**:

```
 age  gender  counting
  10       F         2
  10       M         1
  20       F         1
```

I'm using this code, but it takes too long:

```
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
   freq.loc[np.all(freq['age','gender']==row[2:3],axis=1),'counting'] += 1
```

Is there a faster way to do that?

Please note:

- I have to use **freq** because not all combinations (as for instance *20* and *M*) are desired
- some columns in **df** may not be used
- counting counts how many times both values appear in each row
- freq may have more than 2 values to check for (this is just an small example)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can do it with inner `merge` to filter the combinations in df you don't want, then `groupby` age and gender and `count` the column counting. just reset_index to fit your expected output.

```
freq = (df.merge(freq, on=['age', 'gender'], how='inner')
          .groupby(['age','gender'])['counting'].size()
          .reset_index())
print (freq)
   age gender  counting
0   10      F         2
1   10      M         1
2   20      F         1
```

Depending on the number of combinations you don't want, it could be faster to `groupby` on `df` before doing the `merge` like:

```
freq = (df.groupby(['age','gender']).size()
          .rename('counting').reset_index()
          .merge(freq[['age','gender']])
       )
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to use `reindex` to filter down to freq list:

```
df.groupby(['gender', 'age']).count()\
  .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1['gender'], df1['age']]))
```

Output:

```
            country
gender age         
F      10         2
M      10         1
F      20         1
```

Answer (score 8):

NumPy into the mix for some performance (hopefully!) with the idea of dimensionality-reduction to `1D`, so that we can bring in the efficient `bincount` -

```
agec = np.r_[df.age,freq.age]
genderc = np.r_[df.gender,freq.gender]
aIDs,aU = pd.factorize(agec)
gIDs,gU = pd.factorize(genderc)
cIDs = aIDs*(gIDs.max()+1) + gIDs
count = np.bincount(cIDs[:len(df)], minlength=cIDs.max()+1)
freq['counting'] = count[cIDs[-len(freq):]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [44]: df
Out[44]: 
  country  age gender
0  Brazil   10      F
1     USA   20      F
2  Brazil   10      F
3     USA   20      M
4  Brazil   10      M
5     USA   20      M

In [45]: freq # introduced a missing element as the second row for variety
Out[45]: 
   age gender  counting
0   10      F         2
1   23      M         0
2   20      F         1
```

**Specific scenario optimization #1**

If `age` header is known to contain only integers, we can skip one `factorize`. So, skip `aIDs,aU = pd.factorize(agec)` and compute `cIDs` instead with -

```
cIDs = agec*(gIDs.max()+1) + gIDs
```